# Java Bitmap change hue

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Here is my code:

```
    public static Bitmap processing(Bitmap src, float hue) {
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int newPixel = hueChange(src.getPixel(x, y), hue);
                bitmap.setPixel(x, y, newPixel);
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
    private static int hueChange(int startpixel, float hue) {
        float[] hsv = new float[3];       //array to store HSV values
        Color.colorToHSV(startpixel,hsv); //get original HSV values of pixel
        hsv[0]=hsv[0]+hue;                //add the shift to the HUE of HSV array
        hsv[0]=hsv[0]%360;                //confines hue to values:[0,360]
        return Color.HSVToColor(Color.alpha(startpixel),hsv);
    }
```

Problem is: `processing` takes up to 3300ms if src Bitmap size is 480x480. And it's too long for me.

---

What is the fastest way to do it?

---

**Done!**
The fastest way is to use OpenCV with NDK.

Comment: Not sure what image transformations you are trying to do. Some may be provided by the existing Renderscript ScriptInstrinstics, you could write it in Renderscript or you can look for OpenGL based image processing libraries.

Comment: see `Bitmap#createBitmap(int[] colors, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)` or similar `Bitmap#createBitmap` methods

Comment: no luck? it does not work? returns a null? an empty `Bitmap`?

Comment: @pskink you was right, create Bitmap from an array is fast. Problem was in changing hue functionality. My answer was edited.

Comment: ok so did you try that `ColorFilterGenerator.java` ?

Comment: @pskink yep, it's changing hue pretty fast, but not correct (I compared with Paint tools). As I wrote at the end of my question: problem was solved by using OpenCV with NDK. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

THis is the worst possible way to do this.  If you ever think of using setPixel-  don't.  You're probably wrong.

The right way:

```
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
   canvas.drawColor(color);
```

Comment: he wants to set each pixel with different ARGB

Comment: You're probably best off treating it in C as raw bytes then turning it into a bitmap. Set pixel is just not efficient. Not is doing this kind of work in java, this is one of those things where lack of bounds checking and different memory layouts in C really shine. Or even better, using open gl so you can run it on the gpu